# how to redirect to different view when we click on page numbers in mvc asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

i have implemented one web grid with pagination enabled using webgridextension.cs file. Same page have multiple buttons to perform different actions like search, get excel, get pdf. in order to perform different form submits i used multiplebutton with action selector attribute. when i click on page number down to the grid it was navigating to default action index.

Here i want to navigate to different action GetRFQData with model (already loaded) in the page..

can you please help me on this.

```
WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(null, rowsPerPage: 25, canPage: true, defaultSort: "RFQID");

grid.Bind(Model != null ? Model.RFQSearchResults != null ? Model.RFQSearchResults
                                                 : new List<Shipsurance.Model.RFQ>()
               : new List<Shipsurance.Model.RFQ>(), rowCount: Model != null ? Model.TotalRowsCount :25, autoSortAndPage: false);

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class MultipleButtonAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Argument { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        var isValidName = false;
        var keyValue = string.Format("{0}:{1}", Name, Argument);
        var value = controllerContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue(keyValue);

        if (value != null)
        {
            controllerContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values[Name] = Argument;
            isValidName = true;
        }

        return isValidName;
    }
}

 [MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "GetRFQData")]
    public ActionResult GetData(Shipsurance.Model.RFQ rfqModelData)
    {
        SerachRFQ getRFQDetails = new SerachRFQ();
        return View("Index", getDetails.getResults(rfqModelData));

    }
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RedirectToAction()` method.

```
return RedirectToAction("Your action", model);
```